# Question repeatedly refused for unclear code-formatting reasons

Tags: support, code-formatting, posting, quality-filter

I can't believe how difficult it is to post a question on Stack Overflow. I keep getting the following message:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: Your post appears
>   to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent
>   all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button

I indented every piece of code according to the specifications. I don't know why it's giving me that message.  [Here](http://i48.tinypic.com/2mxmzcp.jpg) [are](http://i50.tinypic.com/b4uble.jpg) screenshots of what I'm trying to enter.

I spent a lot of time trying to format my post to your specifications, but can still not get it posted. What might cause this and what can I do about it?

Comment: Can you show us a screen shot of the editor screen with the post you're trying to enter?

Comment: Or alternatively, post your (rejected) question to a pastebin and share it here.

Comment: Are you sure that **all** your code is properly formatted?

Comment: I know - *only* 3.3m questions managed to get posted successfully so far. Did you stop to consider that the problem might be you?

Comment: @Ernest --- yes I will, give me a few minutes to do it.

Comment: Also thousands of people seem to satisfy the requirements for posting questions every day. So instead of moaning and WTF'ing maybe you could provide some actual details so we can show you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Looking at the quality of questions in SO I think posting them is too easy.

Comment: top part: http://i48.tinypic.com/2mxmzcp.jpg<br/>
bottom part: http://i50.tinypic.com/b4uble.jpg<br/>the python code is indented 4 spaces according to the specifications

Comment: You should not quote the data, but rather format it as code, too. Quote will not preserve new lines.

Comment: Might it have stumbled over some of the numbers in the data, thinking it is code?

Comment: So format the data as code even though it is NOT code? Is that the answer?

Comment: I am sure that it's the second half; those open/close braces on lines  by themselves scream "code". As @UristMcBobby says, indent those data blocks as code, especially that second one.

Comment: Format the data as code, I'll try it. Thanks to everyone that helped.

Comment: The quoted data in the bottom part should show up as a single-line jumble in the preview. That's a big sign that the system will reject it, since it's rarely what the user intends. (It might accept it if you used two spaces at the end of each line to manually insert line breaks, but for JSON you'd be more expected to just code block it.)

Comment: I suggested a, ummm, less-inflammatory title. In general, keeping the question (which is very appropriate) but editing out the frustrated antagonism (which is less so) would be nice :)

Comment: formatting the data as code didn't work and I used 2 spaces at the end of every line, easier than typing in an html line break --- SIGH ---

Comment: Can you post your "code" as an answer here?

Comment: @AaronBertrand He posted it in the comments already

Comment: @MichaelMrozek yes I can see the screen shots, but my point is to be able to take a block of text and enter it into a question until I'm able to post it, to help isolate what is going wrong for the OP. I have no interest in transcribing text from a screen shot, and no guarantee that I'll get all the whitespace / potential non-printing characters right even if I did have that much time and patience.

Comment: How the preview looks with formatting all code and data as code but still getting error message.

1) http://i47.tinypic.com/709zja.jpg
2) http://i50.tinypic.com/2a0kwgj.jpg
3) http://i49.tinypic.com/2vtwmzb.jpg

Comment: Your file content is still not formatted as code. With it containing lots of numbers and ';' that is most likely still tripping it up.

Comment: For those that offered helpful advice the question has now been officially resolved! Thank you! My question has been posted. What an experience...

Comment: I would like to add one more thing that falls back to my original yet highly edited for content question. Just because it looks like code doesn't mean it is code. If it was code I would have formatted that way but my intent was to have it appear as text because that is exactly what it was. Those parts that had to be formatted as code needed to stand out from the actual code, not look like code. Having to try and figure that out made this harder than it needed to be. So the rhetorical question is how do you allow that without people getting lazy and just trying to pass everything off as text?

Comment: *"So format the data as code even though it is NOT code?"* The data should be formatted and display as a literal just like the code should be formatted and displayed as a literal, so yes it should be.

Answer (score 7):

[One of your screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE0lb.jpg) says how to fix the problem:

> Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut

They look similar, but there's a difference between a blockquote, which starts with a `>`:

> blockquote

and a code block, which starts with four spaces:

```
code block
```

If you need to add two spaces to the end of each line to make it wrap, you're using a blockquote; code blocks don't work that way. See the [source of this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6a7aeabe-04d4-4fce-aee8-0cd3bca7db2c/view-source) if that helps

Comment: The root cause here is that the text that needed to be formatted as code wasn't actual code, so the error message was completely misleading.

Comment: @MarkRansom Maybe so, but the question was "what can I do about it". It's pretty common to use code blocks for things other than code; it's more like a verbatim block

Comment: You provided the what but not the why, which leaves the answer less useful than it could be. "It's pretty common" - yes it is, but that wouldn't be known to someone new to the site.

Answer (score 4):

For a general answer, a good place to look for why your post might be tripping the "code formatting" filter is this Programmers.SE question:

[Simple method for reliably detecting code in text?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87611/simple-method-for-reliably-detecting-code-in-text/87622#87622)

That's a question [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) (co-founder of Stack Exchange) asked when they were implementing this feature.  It looks like your data (that you have in blockquote formatting) would trip a few of those simple checks, especially

- "A dot or arrow between two words",
- "Presence of curly braces, brackets",
- "Uncommon characters/operators", and
- "nested parentheses, braces, and/or brackets"

Also, see this search query:

["your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22your%20post%20appears%20to%20contain%20code%20that%20is%20not%20properly%20formatted%20as%20code%22) (sorted by votes)

The questions there have explanations of the filter.  There are also posts by other people that have had similar problems, and how their specific situations were resolved.